# Storing .tex files

Tags: compiling, esami

I have a large database of .tex files that I use to compile via the esami package.  My company designs curriculum for math and science of all levels, so while latex provides beautiful graphics (yay!), I have close to 7,000 tex files that are stored on my hard drive.  These are only the problems - I have another folder full of .pdfs that are often compiled within each problem.  Of course, they are backed up nightly, but surely there must be another way to handle this.  I am interested in creating a better storage system so that the files may be available when I am away from my computer.

I have considered cloud storage, but I was wondering if anyone had any input as to how this will affect compilation speed?  I would assume that running the files directly from my hard drive would be the fastest way to compile, but I would love to hear any advice anyone may have.

Here is an example of a geometry problem (MWE):

This is the shell file that is run in TexWorks using pdfLatex+MakeIndex+Bibtex:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,UKenglish]{article}
\usepackage[shufflerandom,twocolumns,xyz,solutionsonly]{esami}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{xlop}
\usepackage{longdiv}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
{2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
{\normalfont\huge\center\bfseries}}
\makeatother
\setlength{\columnsep}{-4in}
\def\examname{2016/01/16}
\def\numcompiti{1}%%% The number of the versions
\date{2016/01/16}
\def\Data{\longdate}%%% or \shortdate: the date in the heading
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}
g-0621
\testversioni
\pagestyle{esame}
\whiledo{\thevers<\numcompiti}{\stepvers
\FPeval\seme{round((\thenomefile+(3*\thevers)):0)}
\randomi=\seme
\permuta
\begin{large}
\begin{minipage}[t][6.4in][t]{7.5in}

\esercizi{../g-0621}

\end{minipage}
\closevers
}
\end{large}
\end{document}
```

Here is the actual problem file that the code is referring to in the line "\esercizi{../g-0621}"

```
\newproblem{

\begin{problem}Write a formal proof for the following:

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{5cm}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{C:/Teaching/Problems/Diagrams/graph210.pdf}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.10\textwidth}
\begin{minipage}{5cm}
\begin{align*}
\textbf{Given}&:m \angle 2 > m\angle 1\\
\textbf{Prove}&:m \angle 2 > m\angle 4\\
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\textbf{Statement}&\textbf{Reason}\\\hline
\fillin[e]{6cm}{$m \angle 2 > m\angle 1$}&\fillin[e]{6cm}{Given}\\[3ex]\hline
\fillin[e]{6cm}{$m \angle 1 > m\angle 3$}&\fillin[e]{6cm}{Exterior Angle Inequality}\\[3ex]\hline
\fillin[e]{6cm}{$m \angle 2 > m\angle 3$}&\fillin[e]{6cm}{Transitive Property of Inequality}\\[3ex]\hline
\fillin[e]{6cm}{$\angle 3 \cong \angle 4$}&\fillin[e]{6cm}{Vertical Angle Theorem}\\[3ex]\hline
\fillin[e]{6cm}{$m \angle 2 > m\angle 4$}&\fillin[e]{6cm}{Substitution Property}\\[3ex]\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}



\end{problem}

}
```

For the record, if anyone is making a database of problems, I love the esami package.  It has a learning curve, but is really spectacular once you get to know how to use the package.

Finally (and I apologize for the long post), if no one here has a direct answer, I could also test the compilation myself but is there a way to get a documented printout of the compilation speed?

I figured I could just setup the same problem on an external drive, cloud storage and my own desktop and test the 3 to see how much more time it takes to compile when using the other 2 methods.

Comment: Is this really related to (La)TeX?

Comment: I thought I put it in the right place.  Is there another place that I should post this?

Comment: Just keep your question open here and try it parallel on stackoverflow.

Comment: The 'cloud', `ssh`, external drive, the online LaTeX services ... how many options are there really if you want to access 7000 files from everywhere but the computer on which you wrote them?  However, this does seem off-topic: the 'compile time' here would see to be influenced by factors other than the engine itself.

Comment: Also, it depends on kinds of further things which have nothing to do with TeX: which OSs, firewall/security at workplace; policies related etc. etc. ***Somebody at your workplace should advise on this to ensure compliance with company policy.***

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to have your 7.000 files only on a cloud storage or both on your pc and on a cloud storage for backup purpose? 
I often compile files with the esami package and I have sometimes tried to put the master file and the exercises on my pc, synronized on a cloud storage. I did not notice any slowing in the compilation, as far as I turned off the sync feature when I compiled and turned it on when I was finished, to backup my work. 
I am not aware of any tool to trace the compilation time.
I have not tried to compile with files only on a cloud storage, so I cannot help you with this.
As for the external hard disk option, it is even more difficult to evaluate if it affects the compilation time, as it depends on the hard disk speed, on the usb ports speed, and so on.